# TreeGrid in jqGrid not working properly

Tags: jqgrid, treegrid

I am using treegrid with jqGrid and am quite new to this plugin. I am not able to get the treegrid feature working properly. The first time when I click the expand button it works fine. The next time, when I click to collapse, it gives me javascript error:
     `$t.p.data[pos] is undefined` This is in the setTreeNode method of jqGrid.

I hope Oleg or someone will help or give me a pointer.

My configuration is as follows:

```
var grid = $("#grid").jqGrid({
    treeGrid: true,
    treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
    ExpandColumn: 'businessAreaName',
    ExpandColClick : true,
    url:'agileProgramme/records.do',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames:['Id'
              , 'Business Area'
              , 'Investment'
              , 'Org'
              , 'Goal'
    ],
    colModel:[
/*00*/          {name:'agileProgrammeId',index:'agileProgrammeId', width:0, editable:false,hidden:true},
/*01*/          {name:'businessAreaName',index:'businessAreaName', width:160, editable:false},
/*02*/          {name:'programmeName',index:'programmeName', width:150, editable:false, classes:'link'},
/*03*/          {name:'org',index:'org', width:50, editable:false, classes:'orgHierarchy', sortable : false},
/*04*/          {name:'goal',index:'goal', width:70, editable:false}
    ],
    treeReader : {
        level_field: "level",
        parent_id_field: "parent", 
        leaf_field: "leaf",
        expanded_field: "expanded"
    },
    autowidth: true,
    height: 240,
    pager: '#pager',
    sortname: 'id',
    sortorder: "asc",
    toolbar:[true,"top"],
    caption:"TableGridDemo",
    emptyrecords: "Empty records",
    loadonce: true,
    jsonReader : {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: false,
        cell: "cell",
        id: "agileProgrammeId"
    }
});
```

The data returned when the column is expanded is as below.

```
{
   "page":"1",
   "total":"1",
   "records":"1",
   "rows":[
      {
         "agileProgrammeId":2,
         "businessAreaName":"child",
         "programmeName":"childSomething",
         "goal":null,
         "parent":1,
         "level":"1",
         "leaf":true,
         "expanded":false
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is the data which is initially loaded.

```
{
   "page":"1",
   "total":"1",
   "records":"1",
   "rows":[
      {
         "agileProgrammeId":1,
         "businessAreaName":"parent",
         "programmeName":"parentsomething",
         "goal":null,
         "parent":null,
         "level":"0",
         "leaf":false,
         "expanded":false
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: The error `$t.p.data[pos]` seems more as like you have problem with the data first loaded in the grid. Could you include the data returned by `'agileProgramme/records.do'` at the creating of jqGrid. The data should contain the item with the id `475` which is parent of the child node which you posted.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg for the response. I have pasted the initial data.

Comment: Oleg, I do have more extra attributes in the response data apart from the above 5 fields shown. However, in ColModel I have restricted the column for now to only the above 5 cols.

Comment: Updating the question with actual test data after removing the addtional attributes (and still getting the error )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I debugged the grid with the data which you posted and find out that the reason are [the two lines of code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.base.js#L1256-1257) where the local data are removed in case of `loadonce: true`.

TreeGrid save the previous loaded data locally in the same way as `loadonce: true` do in case of "standard" grid. So setting of `loadonce: true` has no sense in case of TreeGrid. Moreover how you know now setting `loadonce: true` in case of TreeGrid has side effects.

So to solve your problem you should just remove `loadonce: true` from the TreeGrid definition.

**UPDATED**: I posted just now [the suggestion](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/treegrid-delete-previous-loaded-local-data-if-loadoncetrue-are-used/#p26247) to eliminate the problem which you have now in the future.